# Post Images on Twitter using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, android

I am trying to make an application which is able to post images on twitter. I need to use javascript for the same. The below code navigates my page to twitter but i dont know how to move ahead. Any help is appreciated.

```
<a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-lang="en">Tweet</a>
<script>

!function(d,s,id){
    var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if(!d.getElementById(id)){
        js=d.createElement(s);
        js.id=id;
        js.src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);
    }
}
(document,"script","twitter-wjs");
</script>
```

Thank you in advance:)

Comment: I have done Project like this, I was uploading images to server from mobile phone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need [Twitter API](https://dev.twitter.com/) which allows you to post new tweets ( Images, .. ) using current logged in user's account.